# preg_replace id="my_id" with id=my_id

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a HTML string containing regular HTML with ID:s and classes in the following way:

```
<div id="my_id"></div>
```

I want to use a preg_replace in PHP to minify the strings in this way:

```
<div id=my_id></div>
```

In other words I want to remove the wrapping quote characters. How do I do this?

Comment: What did you try, what went wrong? At least show some effort :) (anyway, why would you want that? removing those 2 `"` will hardly be noticable in filesize?)

Comment: You're playing with fire. better to leave that quotes.

Comment: I'm not very comfortable writing regexps to be honest, so I tried making some really ugly code looping through the string and removing quote marks.

Comment: It's not noticable for a single user, but when you've gotten a million page loads it will be noticable. :)

Comment: But it will be invalid HTML.

Comment: I honestly can't think of a valid reason why you'd want to do this.

Comment: You cannot have a regex transformation of an html document. It is mathematically not possible. You may only find solutions that will work on some cases, but never all of them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if quotes really matter, then try this:

```
$str = '<div id="my_id">say "good"</div><div id=\'sdafsdaf\'>la\'la</div>';

$str = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+\sid=)([\'"])([^\'"]+)\2/', '$1$3', $str);

// <div id=my_id>say "good"</div><div id=sdafsdaf>la'la</div>
var_dump($str);
```

But I do think save these "quotes" will just bring few benefits, 3% maybe, but compression methods, like gzip, might save 70% normally.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but we need those 3 %. The document is, of course, gzipped to. Everything is stripped down to save every single bit of bandwidth (loads of users).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/"/', '', $matches)
```

Comment: Yeah because the only double-quotes in an html document are the ones around markup attributes values.

Comment: Why do you need `preg_replace()` for something trivial as this? And you'd never want to do this: it will replace ALL double-quotes to single-quotes.

Comment: @AmalMurali I only answered his question. Because that is what he asked.